# How many chapters are in Red Dead Redemption 2's main story?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

In Red Dead Redemption 2, how many chapters does the main story consist of? I have gotten to Chapter 5, so I know that there is at least 5.

I do not want to Google it because I am wary of spoilers and location titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 6 chapters and the epilogue.

[Source](https://www.ign.com/wikis/red-dead-redemption-2/Walkthrough)